# Query ejabberd from a http server

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, ejabberd-module

- I have a mnesia database
- Database has a table with lots of records.
- I want to get all the records from this table from a **node.js** server via `rest` `api` (**http request**)

For eg.

- Node.js server sends a http request to ejabberd server to query that table
- Ejabberd server returns all the records to node.js server.

How can I go this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there is some command that already provides that information, so with ReST you can execute that command.

Alternatively, you can store that information in a SQL database, where probably you already know or can find examples to get the information easily.